# struggling with Input Calculation

Tags: javascript, input, calculation

Hi I am really new to javascript and struggling with getting this code working. So when I click the button after filling the inputs with numbers, nothing happens. Do you know what I am doing wrong in here?

HTML:

```
    <input type="text" id="eing1" placeholder=" z. B. 700&euro;" style="width:80px;">
    <input type="text" id="eing2" placeholder=" z. B. 30000&euro;" style="width:80px;">
    <input type="text" id="eing3" placeholder=" &empty; 225" style="width:80px;">
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Berechnen" onClick="ausgeben()">
   <p id="arbeitszeit"></p>
   <p id="produktivitaetssteigerung"></p>
   <p id="amortisationszeit"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
function ausgeben(){

    var kostentisch = parseInt(document.getElementById("eing1").value)
    var bruttogehalt = parseInt(document.getElementById("eing2").value)
    var arbeitstage = parseInt(document.getElementById("eing3").value)

    var stundenlohn = bruttogehalt/arbeitstage/8;
    var arbeitszeit = arbeitstage*8;
    var produktivitaetssteigerung = arbeitszeit*0.12;
    var amortisationszeit = kostentisch/(arbeitstage/(produktivitaetssteigerung*stundenlohn));

    document.getElementById("stundenlohn").innerHTML=tischsitzen + " Stunden";
    document.getElementById("produktivitaetssteigerung").innerHTML=armlehne + " Stunden";
    document.getElementById("amortisationszeit").innerHTML=stuhl + " Tage";
}
```

Here the js-fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1ej6ezou/

Comment: Concerning the first question, what is the problem you're having?  Additionally, it's a bit unclear to me what "It works for on variable but not for the query selector." means exactly.

Comment: To add eventlisteners to all the selected nodes you might do something like `document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((e) => {e.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){console.log('key up')})})`. I.E. iterate over the selected nodes and add the listener.

Comment: @alaric I edited the question:
When I click the button after filling the inputs with numbers nothing happens, as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/1ej6ezou/

Comment: Within the jsfiddle you've posted at least an error is occurring due to the javascript function "ausgeben" not being found.  Have you verified that the function is available from the page in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind `keyUp` listener as below for more info find snippet below

```
var selectors = document.querySelectorAll("#eing1, #eing2, #eing3");

for (var i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++) {
    selectors[i].addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();
     if (event.keyCode == 13) {
     document.getElementById("button").click();
   }
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="ergonomierechner">
  <p id="h1" style="text-align: center; font-size: 150%; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 5px;">Individueller Ergonomie-Rechner</p>
  
  <center><p id="text" >
   <span>Kosten f&uuml;r Sitz-Stehschreibtisch: </span>
   <input type="text" id="eing1" placeholder=" z. B. 700&euro;" style="width:80px;">
   <span>Bruttogehalt inkl. 20% Lohnnebenkosten: </span>
   <input type="text" id="eing2" placeholder=" z. B. 30000&euro;" style="width:80px;">
   <span>J&auml;hrliche Arbeitstage: </span>
   <input type="text" id="eing3" placeholder=" &empty; 225" style="width:80px;">
   <input id="button" type="button" value="Berechnen" onClick="ausgeben();">
  </p></center>
  
  <div id="fehler"></div>
  
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
   <th>Arbeitszeit:</th>
   <th>Produktivit&auml;tssteigerung pro Tag (12&#037;):</th>
   <th>Amortisationszeit:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
   <td><p id="arbeitszeit"></p></td>
   <td><p id="produktivitaetssteigerung"></p></td>
   <td><p id="amortisationszeit"></p></td>
    </tr>
  </table> 
 
 </div>
  
  <script>
  function ausgeben(){
  
  var kostentisch = parseInt(document.getElementById("eing1").value)
  var bruttogehalt = parseInt(document.getElementById("eing2").value)
  var arbeitstage = parseInt(document.getElementById("eing3").value)
  
  var stundenlohn = bruttogehalt/arbeitstage/8;
  var arbeitszeit = arbeitstage*8;
  var produktivitaetssteigerung = arbeitszeit*0.12;
  var amortisationszeit = kostentisch/(arbeitstage/(produktivitaetssteigerung*stundenlohn));

//Changes to be made here
  document.getElementById("arbeitszeit").innerHTML=arbeitszeit + " Stunden";
  document.getElementById("produktivitaetssteigerung").innerHTML=produktivitaetssteigerung + " Stunden";
  document.getElementById("amortisationszeit").innerHTML=amortisationszeit + " Tage";
 }
  </script>
```

Comment: @Krystian Manthey please find updated snippet above it'll work or find [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ej6ezou/2/)

Comment: thank you very much! Like I see a copy and paste failure of mine

Comment: Last three line of `ausgeben()` method where you are getting elements where you wants to update calculations `document.getElementById("arbeitszeit")`,`document.getElementById("produktivitaetssteigerung")` and `document.getElementById("amortisationszeit").innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

First, I noticed that in the JavaScript part your referencing to the element ID `stundenlohn`  that doesnt exist in any HTML tag shown.

For the button, I would personally give a class name or a new attribte like `<input type="text" data-event-target id="..." value="..." />` to the elements from which I want to catch the event. Once I gived the target elements a new attribute (`data-enter-target` in this case) I would use JS to add an event listener on each of them.

```html
<style>
   /* I put the style outside the element 
    * so if I need to change a value, the
    * changes will apply to all the elements 
    * that has this class.
    */

    * {color: black;}

    .w-80 {
        width: 80px;
    }
    
    p {text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;}
    .color-0 {background-color: #0FA;}
    .color-1 {background-color: #FF0;}
    .color-2 {background-color: #F0F;}
    .color-3 {background-color: #0F0;}
    .color-4 {background-color: #00F;}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <!-- Here are the three input on which I added -->
    <!-- the "data-enter-target" attribute -->
    <input type="text" data-enter-target id="input-1" class="w-80" value="Value Here"  />
    <input type="text" data-enter-target id="input-2" class="w-80" value="Second value"  />
    <input type="text" data-enter-target id="input-3" class="w-80" value="Third value"  />

    <!-- Other elements like paragraphs -->
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p>Click several times</p>
    
    <!-- Add the submit button and add it an onclick function -->
    <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit()"/>
</div>
<script>
    // Retrieve all the elements that contains the attribute
    // and store them in a variable as an array.
    var targets = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-enter-target]');
    
    // Then for each element
    targets.forEach(function(current_element, index) {
        // Add the event listener on the element
        current_element.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
            // Check if the key pressed is 'Enter'
            if(event.key == "Enter") { // You could also use the keycode (Enter=13)
                // Do the thing you wanna do when Enter is pressed
                // In this case we wanna trigger the onclick event of the submit button
                document.getElementById('myButton').click();
            }
        });
    });
    
    // Add the function called when the button is clicked
    function btnSubmit(event) {
        // Do whatever you want when the button is clicked
        alert('Hey!!! The button has been clicked!');

        // Ex: You could replace or add content to an existing element
        document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(function(element) {
            element.innerHTML='<span class="color-'+parseInt(Math.random()*5)+'">Bob loves potatoes!</span>';
        });
    }
</script>
```